# Can anyone explain with multidimensional arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to this and am very confused. How do I set arr[55000][7], save the values in server (using ASP.NET with C#) and increase the array range whenever needed. I did not find a method to change two dimensional array size in C#.

In addition, my requirement is:

```
Variable Name      Values 
Variable 1           =  ( 2, 4) , ( 5, 1)           
Variable 2            =   ( 7, 4) , ( 1, 3)           
Variable 3            =   ( 5, 7) , ( 5, 1)           
Variable 4            =   ( 2, 4) , ( 2, 1)             
Variable 5            =   ( 9, 8) , ( 2, 4)           
Variable 6            =   ( 3, 4) , ( 5, 7)           
Variable 7            =   ( 4, 7) , ( 4, 2)           
Variable 8           =   ( 5, 4) , ( 5, 7)
Etc….    
(This data will be stored on server.) 

Now for example user give input variable 1, 4, 5, 7
The calculator will show result =( 2, 4).
```

I am getting to work on this but with no help. Can anyone guide me in this please

Comment: Arrays cant change in size in c# use `List<T>` instead

Comment: Since .NET 2.0, Array.Resize() can be used to re-allocate an array. Array.Resize() creates a new array, copies the content of the old array into the new array and replaces the passed array reference with a reference to the new array.

Comment: Thanks Nils and schgab, I really appreciate if you can give me an example on the thing.

Comment: Use List<T> ,you will be able to dynamically add or removed elements and you will save yourself a lot of pain.

Comment: with List<T> I will not be able to access the elements using variable names right, If that can be done, I will look into it. Please confirm

Comment: A list can be also accessed the same way as an array is. So if you are referring to [][] notation , yes you can. Perhaps if you can post what you written, code wise , I can be of more help

Comment: If provided answer has helped, etiquette is to mark this as "the answer" and probably upvote its usefulness. 
This prevents this question coming up under "show unanswered questions" in SOF and also gives some more reputation to the person who helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a simple implementation for a list of lists:

```
       List<List<int>> myList = new List<List<int>>();

       myList.Add(new List<int>());
       myList.Add(new List<int>());
       myList.Add(new List<int>());


       int list = 0;
       int element = 6;

       myList[0].Add(5);
       myList[list].Add(element);
```

If we inspect my list we have

[image]

You can then add or remove as you wish.

**Edit**

if you want to use a string name such as "Variable" 1 to get or set those values we need to change the structure a little.

First we declare a structure to hold the values in pair.

```
    class Valuegroup
    {
        public int FirsValue { get; set; }
        public int SecondValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Then what we need is collection key values pair, where the key must be unique. In .Net we can use Dictionary structure to achieve it.

We declare it as following:

```
        Dictionary<string, List<Valuegroup>> myList = new Dictionary<string, List<Valuegroup>>();
```

With the above declaration we will be able to use the key string Variable 1 , Variable 2 , Variable 3 ect as unique key. Then we can add our values as groups in the `List<Valuegroup>`. Each list element will represent a group of items such as (2, 4) , (5, 1) etc.

Putting it all together:

```
    class Valuegroup
    {
        public int FirsValue { get; set; }
        public int SecondValue { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Variable 1 = (2, 4) , (5, 1)

        Valuegroup first = new Valuegroup
        {
            FirsValue = 2,
            SecondValue = 4
        };

        Valuegroup second = new Valuegroup
        {
            FirsValue = 5,
            SecondValue = 1
        };

        Dictionary<string, List<Valuegroup>> myList = new Dictionary<string, List<Valuegroup>>();
        myList.Add("Variable 1",new List<Valuegroup>{first,second});

        //retrive a value using a key name eg Variable 1
        List<Valuegroup> temp = new List<Valuegroup>();
        myList.TryGetValue("Variable 1", out temp);

        //do a search using Linq
        var t = myList.Where(x => x.Key == "Variable 2");
    }
```

This shows what myList contains

[image]

And here you can see that getting a value using key `"Variable 1"` return the correct result. Meanwhile doing a search for `"Variable 2"` held no results.

[image]

Comment: Hi Alex, Can I perform a search on the List, In my above example, Can I make a search using variable names like common search on elements in  Variable 1, variable 4, variable 5, Variable 7 should return result (2,4). If you can tell me it is possible with a small example, I will go head with this. Just wanted to make sure all my requirements will be satisfied if I go with lists. Please clarify me on this with a code if possible.

Comment: @Deepak I have made some changes to the proposed solution. This should provide you an explanation and an approach in how to resolve your issue.